# mdx building set from external file

Tags: mdx

I am trying to build a 'dynamic' MDX which will take an external file (which has one column multiple rows) as an input to build a set. Then the set will be used as part of the mdx. I am not sure is this even doable? I am from t-sql back ground, it's pretty doable in t-sql, how about mdx?

Comment: Two easy ways come to mind: dynamically integrate the data from the file into your MDX statement while you create it e. g. in a `WITH set [my set] AS { [Dim].[attrib].[mbr1], ... }`, or load the file via an ETL process an make it available within the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

last week I published the MDX script injection projects on codepelx.

https://mdxscriptinjection.codeplex.com/

The MDX script can be easily updated or extended with code without the need 
 to deploy the cube again. This can be very useful when MDX script will 
 dynamically expand to for e.g.

- update cube side SETs
- generate SETs from external data source like SQL querys or XML content
- create dynamic CALUCALATE MEMBER
- update whole section in MDX script

Any feedback or proposalis very welcome. Do not hesitate to contact me.

Regards,

Marco